# How to keep web page same ratio on a mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my desktop web site to appear just as it is on a mobile device, knowing that everything I read on the mobile device will be smaller.  I basically don't want any elements to fold just because its on a smaller screen.  Is there a meta tag or a media query that will provide this adjustment?

This is what I am currently usig for my header...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
....
</head>
```

thanks

Comment: Check into setting a css file for mobile [this tutorial might be helpful](http://www.garron.me/en/blog/creating-an-alternate-css-for-mobiles.html) in figuring out what to do.

Comment: Why do you want this? You need to think of web design differently. You shouldn't cripple a mobile device by serving them a design that doesn't adapt to the smaller screen. Look through the other comments and answers for tips on responsive web design.

Comment: @aaronburrows, its a temporary fix to a problem I am now facing, but don't have to much design time to modify.  thats all.  at the very least, the front-end user needs to see all the data, or at least be able to scroll it, without seeing my HTML elements fold in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

[CSS Tricks has a tutorial for providing different CSS for different browser window sizes](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) (which is a more useful metric then display resolution).

Or you could always build your site to be responsive off the bat, such as using percentages and em's - There are many tutorials out there to show you how to build a completely responsive site.

Answer (score 0):

A meta tag would suit your needs

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Would this be cross-browser compatible?

Comment: Yes, this meta tag simply scales your content to device scale width.

Comment: Neat. Cheers. Helpful for me as well!

Comment: `maximum-scale=1` makes your site unreadable on small devices. Responsive/fluid layout is the way to go.

Comment: yea, definitely don't use the maximum-scale option.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could look into here:

1. Responsive Web Design
2. Scalable units in your CSS (ems and %)

However, some elements which are just resized/scaled may look ridiculous in some of the many different viewport sizes. You may wish to consider not using certain elements which are too large or too small for a viewport size. Hence @media query

Answer (score -1):

Most smart phones will resize your desktop web site as needed. So, you shouldn't have to do anything.